# How to add a dictionary into list?

Tags: list, dictionary

I have a dictionary in the form of a string and I need to add the string_dictionary  to the list as a regular dictionary, because I need to enter the list and then the dictionary, like this:

```
Source[0]["name"]
```

But, the dictionary in the list is in "" and python not consider it like a dictionary.

```
dictionary = "{'name': 'liam', 'last name': 'something'}"
Source = [
    dictionary,
]


print(Source)
```

Output:

```
["{'name': 'liam', 'last name': 'something'}"]
```

Comment: That's because that is not a dictionary, it's a string. Try removing the double quotes at the end.

Comment: I know i have a text file that i take the {'name': 'liam', 'last name': 'something'} from so i need to convert the string to a dictionary

Answer (score 0):

To parse the string to a dictionary, you can use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```py
from ast import literal_eval

dictionary = "{'name': 'liam', 'last name': 'something'}"
Source = [
    literal_eval(dictionary),
]


print(Source[0]["name"])
```

Prints:

```
liam
```

Comment: Ohhhh, Thanks. 